# get an array of Photos in ios Photo Library query by day

Tags: ios

I want when I input day. Does iOS have any property to know or which function for us to get all Photos in iOS Library on that day? Or we must call for loop with all photos to get which photos in that day?

```
- (void)getAllPhotosInCameraRoll {
NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray array];

[self.defaultLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
    if (group) {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if (result) {
                NSMutableDictionary *dicPhoto = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                [dicPhoto setObject:result forKey:@"alassert"];
                [dicPhoto setObject:@1 forKey:@"isHidden"];
                [temp addObject:dicPhoto];
            }
        }];
        self.arrayLibraryPhotos = temp;
        [self.photosCollection reloadData];
    }

} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {

}];}
```

Comment: Are you using `ALAsset`? If So please provide part of your code.

Comment: I edited provide my code. This code is just get all images

Comment: [Is this relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638567/how-can-i-get-image-created-date-time-or-last-modified-date-time-from-ios-photos/10844251#10844251)?

Comment: tks @UmangBista .got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSDate *myDate = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];` and then just query or group it the way you want to in your app.

Comment: Tks @jeraldo. I got it